# How to enact styles with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use inline styles with React.js, but I keep running into errors:

In my render function, I have:

```
render: function() {
    var style = this.state.submitted ? {{"backgroundColor": "#1abc9c", "opacity": "0.6"}} : {{}}; 
    return (
      <div>

        <h1 className="home-two-question" style={style}>{text}</h1>

      </div>
    )
  },
```

Basically I want to toggle this style on click.  However, when I run this, I get an error from React.js.  What is the correct syntax for inline styles in React.js?  Thank you!

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
var style = this.state.submitted ? {{"backgroundColor": "#1abc9c", "opacity": "0.6"}} : {{}};
```

you're just in plain JavaScript, not inside of a JSX tag. Thus, you just want to use single `{}`, not double `{{}}`:

```
var style = this.state.submitted ? {"backgroundColor": "#1abc9c", "opacity": "0.6"} : {};
```

In particular, when you do something like:

```
<div style={{"backgroundColor": "white"}}>
```

There is one set of `{}` to denote that the value of the `style` prop should be interpreted as JavaScript, and another set of `{}` to denote that you are constructing an object within that value.